# Invoking a method from stored class reference

Tags: c++, templates, callback, c++17, std-function

I am working on a callback template class where the callback isn't function or functor but a class reference. Depending on the context, the callback is invoked by calling specific method from registered class, roughly implemented as follows:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class callback
{
public:
   // ctors, moves, copies, assignments, ...

   template<typename F, typename ... A>
   void invoke(F method_ptr, A ... args)
   {
      (*m_interface_ptr.*method_ptr)(std::forward<A>(args) ...);
   }

private:
   T * m_interface_ptr;
};
```

Now, the usage of such template looks something like this:

```cpp
struct intf
{
   virtual void method_a() { ... }
   virtual void method_b(int n) { ... }
};

intf i;

callback<intf> c;
c.subscribe(i);
c.invoke(&intf::method_a);
c.invoke(&intf::method_b, 7);
```

This code works just fine, but the part where I am calling a method from class reference feels a bit odd. Trouble comes if I try to extend the `callback` class to support both class reference callbacks and functor or plain function callbacks.

**Is there a standard way of storing the class reference and invoking methods on it? Something like `std::function` but supporting my case.**

---

**Usecase #1: Calling a method from stored class reference**

```cpp
intf i;
// Create some std:: reference wrapper which allows custom method calls by name
std::some_ref_callable ri(i);
// Pass into callback and invoke
callback<std::some_callable<intf>> ci(ri);
ci.invoke(&intf::method_b, 7);
```

**Usecase #2: Calling a lambda**

```
auto l = []{ /* generic lambda */ };
callback<decltype(l)> cf(l);
cf.invoke();
```

**Usecase #3: Calling a plain function**

```
void func(int n){ /* plain function with param */ }
callback<decltype(func)> cf(func);
cf.invoke(1337);
```

---

Possible custom implementation would look something like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct some_ref_callable
{
    template<typename R, typename ... A>
    auto operator ()(R(T:: * method_ptr)(A ...), A ... args)
    {
        return (*m_object_ptr.*method_ptr)(std::forward<A>(args) ...);
    }
 
    T * m_object_ptr = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: What's `callback_intf`, and how, if at all, is it related to `intf`?

Comment: Looks like you *might* be wanting to look at `std::invoke`, but it's hard to tell with such an incomplete example.

Comment: What do you mean by "functor or plain function callbacks"? Could you show examples of all the use cases you want to get working?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, I made a naming change and forgot to edit the rest of code example. Gonna fix in question, also with the examples you requested.

Comment: You could provide two overloads for `invoke`. Something like `template<typename R, typename... Params, typename ... A> void invoke(R (T::*method_ptr)(Params...), A ... args)` plus the plain vanilla `template <typename... Args> void invoke(Args...);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am quite sure that I can write such a wrapper myself or a custom invocation function but this feels like a common problem so it made me wondering if there is a standard way of doing this. Either through standard library or some popular third-party library.

Comment: @jcmana in your Usecase #1, isn't `ci` has nothing to do with `ri` and `i`?

Comment: @jcmana in your use case #2 and #3, I mean ... isn't it exactly `std::function`?

Comment: @appleapple Yes, in usecase #1 I forgot to pass it into the callback ctor. In usecase #2 and #3, you are also right, I can store it as std::function. The point is I want to do the same in #1, store the reference to object and call methods on it.

Comment: @jcmana I don't get it, you cannot invoke a member (or free) function on case 2 & 3 (and which doesn't make sense to do so either), what's exactly would it be used?

Comment: @appleapple Adding some idea how the wrapper interface could look like.

Comment: no, I'm saying #1 invoke the parameter (and pass stored value as parameter), but it's not the case with #2 and #3 (invoke it's stored callable). the use case is completely different.

Comment: @appleapple Yes, that is the behaviour I wanna unify using some standard approach or library.